# vscode no autocompleta las instancias de Vue en los ficheros .js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, autocompletar, vscode

Cuando creo una instancia de Vue, `new Vue (opciones)`, no tengo autocompletado. He intentado crear una instancia de este modo:

```
new Vue.default (opciones)
```

Y si tiene autocompletado, pero me lanza que Vue.default no es un constructor. Estoy usando Visual Studio Code, con la extensión vetur instalada. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que funcionen los autocompletados?

Comment: si en el complemento no dice como auto completar (Details) , puedes intentar ver en el command palette (Crlt+Shift+P) talvez aparezca ahi , si eso no funciona quizas haya conflicto con otro complemento(poco probable)

Comment: Vetur no tiene ningun comando para autocompletar, pienso que vetur solo posibilita el autocompletamiento en ficheros .vue